# Как удалить комментарии а файле, которые начинаются с //?

Tags: php, файлы, строки

Как удалить комментарии а файле, которые начинаются с // ?

Answer (score 1):

Есть функция `file()`, получает содержимое файла в виде массива построчно. Перебирать циклом и удалять если есть '//' в начале.